# Почему Visit в ExpressionVisitor так странно реализован?

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, если посмотреть [код](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Expressions/ExpressionVisitor.cs), то видно, что там здоровенный switch, который выбирает нужную реализацию.

Собственно вопрос, а почему майки сделали именно так?

Ведь, вроде, все должно быть наоборот и посетитель должен передаваться в класс, где автоматом из коробки будет выбирать нужна перегрузка метода Visit...

Comment: Там а) выбор идет по вложенному полю switch (exp.NodeType) б) И вообще это enum, по которому перегрузку не сделать.

Comment: @vitidev, а почему через enum это намутили, а не через какое-нибудь наследование?

Comment: Не знаю. Может быть решили не плодить множество классов.

Comment: так вроде [нет switch](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/ExpressionVisitor.cs,f0615a823a9efe36)

Comment: @Grundy Хм... А на гитхабе в коре есть... Может они другой подход выбрали зачем-то...

Comment: @iluxa1810, просто ты не тот класс смотришь.